# How do websites that aren't very different from their peers do SEO?

Tags: seo

I'm new to SEO (but I know the basics). I've looked up several videos on youtube so far and the common factor among all of them is good content. The videos I've watched or the SEO tips I've read mostly focus on the strategy of creating good content by writing articles, getting others to contribute and link to them, and so on. With superior content, they can capture the attention of domain experts, or brands, or related websites, etc. and get backlinks/social shares from them.

However, aren't there some keywords for which one doesn't necessarily need good content? For example, something like "mechanic jobs" or "delivery boy jobs", and so on. Another example would be something like, "join pdf" or "compress pdf". The top results for such searches don't have any content at all, rather, just webpages that list the jobs or webpages that provide the joining/compression service. For example, please refer to these:

(searched for "delivery boy jobs")

https://www.naukri.com/delivery-boy-jobs-in-andheri-east-mumbai

https://www.indeed.co.in/Delivery-Boy-jobs-in-Airoli,-Maharashtra

(It's clear that the top results given above are customized according to my location, even though I didn't include any location in my search term)

What do sites as given in the above examples do to be so high in the rankings?

Of course, one obvious reason could be that they've been around for a long time and have the first mover advantage, but I can't understand how sites can "growth hack" their way to good page rankings without having any scope to create quality content, and therefore, without any means to distinguish themselves significantly from their peers.
Do none of the SEO "growth hacking" techniques apply to sites like these?

Comment: There can be lots of reasons and we won't know them.

Answer (score 0):

Well... your first link show 26 "Delivery boy jobs" inside a site that have hundreds of "jobs" offers;
The second link show 10 out of 480 boy jobs in a site that have hundreds of "jobs" offers;
if I pick lower in the page, that will not be exactly as your one depending on location, I will get [this site](https://www.olx.com.pk/islamabad/jobs/q-delivery-boy/)
that has only 8 offers.
So still the content, in this case "amount of offers related" place up or down a website.
This is not a results of hundreds of query, I just try one and already can see the prevalence of content.
Of course SEO it is much more than this 5 minutes check...

Comment: Fair enough, but what about sites related to pdf joining, pdf compression, inter-file format conversion, etc.?

Comment: It could be a specific keyword (pdf joining) combine with other factors. For example, but not only, the first result has 4852 link from social network (try this or other tools: http://www.seoreviewtools.com/website-authority-checker/ ), another result in third page has only 24. If you do a search instead with "pdf merge software" you will see again a more content oriented results. But factors are many not even excluding the presence of https instead of http, speed, mobile compatibility, relevance call to action... Anyway, what kind of website do you have in mind?

Comment: The kind of website that I have in mind is a job portal. I asked around on another forum and also looked up Quora [link](https://www.quora.com/Which-are-the-best-SEO-strategies-for-jobs-portal-site). The forum answer indicates that brand awareness should be built first through conventional marketing and the Quora answer lists down a checklist of steps to take. But all of them are conventional steps well-known to the tech team here. Is there any way I can research on "growth hacks" specifically, rather than the conventional steps?

Comment: From my experience a fast way in SEO is the slowest because then you have to redo all steps and start with a slow way later on. Some suggestions: use a CMS faster than your competitors, a proper domain with one keyword inside (even if not so important like in the past still play a role in SEO) except if you have an already established brand, buy SSL, in any sector of your website write a long article about the sector. Avoid useless stuff, keep as many links as possible visible. Must: responsive design the fastest you can find. Dont spend time on the look but focus on user experience and speed.